# DistributionNotFound: 'six>=1.4.0' is required

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller, apscheduler, six

I'm trying to make an exe out of a Python file that uses apscheduler, sqlalchemy, and Tkinter among other libraries. Once compiled, the majority of the app works fine, except for one function that needs to add jobs to the SQLite database. The most recent error is involving this six library. I've tried downgrading it to 1.4.0, even using '--collect-all six' but that just doesn't launch the app.

I don't know what this six library is really used for.

Comment: Can you try adding "import six" to your main script and report results? Alternatively, try installing the newest version of six in the venv used to produce the exe.

Comment: Yup I tried import six already. No dice. I also saw somewhere that six required this packaging library, tried importing that as well but no luck. And yes I've tried the latest, oldest, and specific versions of six but to no avail

Comment: I'm using apscheduler to create a cron job, this job's information would be stored in a pre formatted SQLite database. This is exactly when the error arises

Comment: This is a long shot, but if `six` really has something to do with Python 2 to 3 transition, you can try to remove it from your EXE by excluding `lib2to3` in your spec file.

Comment: Update: so I transferred all of my files to another laptop that had Python and anaconda freshly installed. I didn't update any packages, kept the same imports, and the exe works fine. I think the problem might be that I had conflicting versions of Python on my own computer. I will troubleshoot until I find the answer